# Appending Lists Bug... The bug is in lineone.append(addString)

Tags: python, string, list

```
while choice!=5:
        if choice==1:
            print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            print "What line do you want to add a player to?"
            print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            line = input("Select a Line")
            while line<4:
                if choice==1:
                    addString = raw_input("Who do you want to sign to line one?")
                    lineone.append(addString)
                    print "Chosen to add " + addString
                elif choice==2:
                    addStr = raw_input("Who do you want to sign to line two?")
                    linetwo.append(addString)
                    print "Chosen to add " + addString
                elif choice==3:
                    addStr = raw_input("Who do you want to sign to line three?")
                    linethree.append(addString)
                    print "Chosen to add " + addString
            print "I am sorry, this is not a valid line"
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us a bit more information about what's going wrong. Are you getting an error message? If so, what?

Comment: @Grizz answered your issue, it seems. As an aside, I think your last `print` statement should be indented once more and buried in an `else` statement

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that, if you select choice 2 or 3, there is no value for the variable addString... you have lines of:

```
addStr = raw_input...
```

instead of:

```
addString = raw_input...
```

...as you have in choice 1.

Comment: File "interface.txt", line 38, in main
    lineone.append(addString)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @user3337936 Edit your question to show where you define `lineone` then, because it sounds like you've done something like `import lineone`!

Comment: Yes... we can't see the init of lineone, and it's apparently NOT a list, since it doesn't have an 'append' method.  Even something like a:  lineone = []    early on should init it.